# Get listed bluetooth devices uuid with out pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, android-broadcast, android-bluetooth

I can list out `bluetooth`devices available, but I am not getting the server `bluetooth`device's `UUID`.
my purpose is to list out number of `bluetooth server` (another android device/s) available. I am not even sure how can I recognize my server device/s from all the `bluetooth`devices available.

- For the first mensioned issue, I used fetchUuidsWithSdp() also, but I am getting `null`value in the UUID `broadcast receiver`. Somebody please help, 
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to get the UUIDs with out pairing..???

Comment: `Get listed bluetooth devices uuid with out pairing` - You mean no need connected to the devices, still can get UUID? This case require the devices support this feature, like Beacon. If the beacon already support, you can scan via BLE and get UUID.

Answer (score 0):

```
bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

if(bluetooth != null)
    {
        String status;
        if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
            String mydeviceaddress = bluetooth.getAddress();
            String mydevicename = bluetooth.getName();
            status = mydevicename + " : " + mydeviceaddress;
            bluetooth.startDiscovery();
        }
        else
        {
            status = "Bluetooth is not Enabled.";
        }
    }
```

And in Broadcast Receiver

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {               
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(intent.getAction())) 
        {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String uuid = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA);

        }
}
```

Comment: I did the same, but When i get BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND, uuid is null

Comment: My understanding: UUID list will be obtained using SDP for peer device, maybe for SDP device pairing is required.